# Delete items from an array's specific index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of 12 items For each of these 4 items I have a button.

```
Button 1 - the first 4 items

Button 2 - the next 4 items

Button 3 - the last 4 items
```

Each of these buttons has a count attribute.

I want to create a function which makes use of that count attribute where if I click on any of these buttons, their corresponding items from the array get removed from the array.
So first button removes the first four items, the second button removes the next four items etc.

Right now my code removes the inputs matching their button, but I want to remove them from `arr` as I explained earlier.

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='0'>Remove</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='1'>Remove</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='2'>Remove</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let arr = [];
inputs.forEach(input => {
  arr.push(input);
})
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  })
})
```

https://codepen.io/make96/pen/YzvGyez?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to, whenever you need to access the array, filter the element items by whether they're connected or not.

```
const filteredArr = arr.filter(elm => elm.isConnected);
```

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.get-inputs)');
const arr = [...inputs];
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  });
});

document.querySelector('.get-inputs').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const filteredArr = arr.filter(elm => elm.isConnected);
  console.log(filteredArr);
});
```

```html
<button class="get-inputs">get inputs</button>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='0'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='1'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='2'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it inside the click handler if you want, and reassign the array to the filtered array.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.get-inputs)');
let arr = [...inputs];
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    arr = arr.filter(elm => elm.isConnected);
  });
});

document.querySelector('.get-inputs').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<button class="get-inputs">get inputs</button>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='0'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='1'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type='button' count='2'>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `isConnected`. I can't find decent documentation on what "connected" means. Is it that it is at the same depth within the same ancestor element?

Comment: Is there any way that I can call this function inside my clickEvent?
I want to display the remaining items in the array after I click that button. I can't add any other one besides the three of them.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected. Yes, you can filter inside the click handler if you want - see the second snippet.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I saw that doc, but it doesn't define the word "connected". It's not clear to me why all elements in the entire document are not directly or indirectly connected to one another.

Comment: There's https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#connected. An element is connected if it's inside a document. If it's not - for example, `document.createElement('div')` - it's just floating around without an ancestor document and isn't considered connected.

Comment: Aha, never mind, I now realise what your code is doing. Very nice approach.